# want to access the dynamic id in c# selenium driver

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

> Want to write selenium c# driver code for edit and delete field but id
>   is always change then how to edit
>   `<tr role="row" class="odd moveCursor ng-scope ng-pristine ng-valid" order="1"`fieldid="30994" id="30994" ng-model="CustomFieldObjectData">
>       `-<td>Sale Price</td>`
>   -Number, Currency
>       `-<td></td>`
>   -
>       `-<td>`
>   -
>       `-<a onclick="deleteActivityfield(30994)" href="#" class="ml-4 btn btn-clearlyInventory-circle btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>-</a></td></tr>
>   -<`enter code here`tr role="row" class="odd moveCursor ng-scope ng-pristine ng-valid" order="1" fieldid="30993" id="30993" ng-model="CustomFieldObjectData">`
>   cUSTOMER
>       `<td>Number, Currency</td>`
>   
>       `<td></td>`
>   enter code here
>       `<a id="30993" class="Updatecustom btn btn-clearlyInventory-circle btnPrimary"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>`
>   
>   `

Answer (score 0):

If IDs are being generated randomly every time then there is no way of predicting them beforehand.

You should try getting the elements by [Xpath](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath).

If that is not an option then try fetching all elements by class and then picking out the relevant ones based on their text.